# Checking if array is contained in another array in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, contains

There is an array[10,20] and I want to know if it is a subset of array[20,30,10] or not. Is there a postgresql function or operation to determine if one array contains another?

Desired outcomes:

```
[10,20] and [30,20,10] - true
[10,20] and [10,30]    - false
[10,20] and [20,10]    - true
[10,20] and [10,20]    - true
```

Comment: 'An array in PostgreSQL'?? Is this part of some code block? If not, what data structures are we talking about?

Comment: @JanDoggen Arrays exist in PostgreSQL at least since [version 7](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/arrays.html), first released in 2001. So I didn't get your question, or the reason why this question was closed.

Comment: @Rodrigo The reason why this question was closed is clearly written in the blue box at the top

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes, I've seen it and disagree. Many questions don't show half of this, and they're still open, and sometimes with hundreds, if not thousands, of upvotes. If one understands what arrays are, the question is perfectly clear. And I also didn't understand your question. "What data structures?" Arrays, of course!

Comment: @JanDoggen I also do not understand why this was closed. Could you explain further? Your response "The reason why this question was closed is clearly written in the blue box at the top" is very unhelpful and not descriptive to people less experienced on the site. This question and the accepted answer below was extremely helpful to me and I assume the 7k other viewers this question has had since 2014. Please reconsider reopening the question for new updated answers in the future. Please explain why you think it is off topic and should remain closed if you disagree.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Like this,perhaps:

```
SELECT ARRAY[10,20]  <@ ARRAY[30,20,10];
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: Worked like charm.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html explains other ones too but <@ was exactly what I needed!